# How to select rows based on string options in html vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

I need to add new rows based on the select options.
If my option is "kfc" I need to select a particular row. If my selected option is "cemrt", I need to add another row.

```
<div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Booked</label>
 <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.name">
 <option value="SEENAT">SEENAT</option>
 <option value="CEMRT">CEMRT</option>  
 <option value="KFC">KFC</option>  
 </select>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" v-if="bok.name == SEENAT"> //NOT WORKING FROM HERE
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Arms(if any)</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data.head" required="">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" v-if="bok.name == KFC">
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
 <label class="control-label">Arms(if any)</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  required="">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But I am using this code not able to add rows based on the options.

My vue js code is

```
addForm = new Vue({
el: "#addForm",
  data: {
      rules : [{
        name:null,
        section:null,
        data   : [{head:null,value:null}]
    }],  
},
  methods: {
     addNewRules: function() {
      this.rules.push({ name: null, section: null,data [{head:null,value:null}] });
    },

},

});
```

If I use option value as 1,2,3 etc. I am getting the result.

But I need to send SEENAT,CEMRT,KFC as data. How can I able to achieve the result.

Comment: recreate your problem here? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. A reproduction on codesandbox would be welcome.
What I can see in your code at a first glance :

1) You forgot quotes around the options keys and thus it expects a constant. The fact you're using double equals instead of triple doesn't help:

```
v-if="bok.name === 'SEENAT'" // this
v-if="bok.name == SEENAT" // instead of that
```

2) data should be a function:

```
data() {
  return {
    rules: [
      {
        name: null,
        section: null,
        data: [{ head: null, value: null }]
      }
    ]
  };
},
```